# Image(Absolute Positioned) Horizontally center in a Relative Positioned container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to center an absolute positioned image  horizontally in a relative positioned container. I tried to do with **css**. But I could't and i did in `Jquery`

http://jsfiddle.net/CY6TP/ [This is i tried to do in Jquery]

**`**Guys can anyone help me to do this in CSS.**`**

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a generic solution but i thought it would give an idea;                                                    .a{                                                              margin-bottom: 50%;
margin-top: 50%;
margin-left: 30%;
margin-right: 30%;                                                                                      }

Comment: @berdem thanks..... But check the answer its good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all in css like this :

```
a{
position : absolute ;
height : 10px;
width : 100px;
top : 50%; 
margin-top : -5px;
left : 50%; 
margin-left : -50px;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eX4z7/)

Comment: This i like very much...Thanks brother

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var width=$('.main').width();
var height=$('.main').height();


$('a').css(
{
"position":"absolute",
"bottom":"50%",
"margin-top":(height/2),
"left":(width/2)-50

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CY6TP/5/)

**UPDATE**

In CSS

```
.main a{
   bottom:50%;
    margin-top:-150px;   
    position:absolute;
    left:75px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CY6TP/13/)

Comment: Dear Brother Thanks for the Help. I mentioned in Question that i nedd this in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try this to make it horizontally center

```
a{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

OR this to make it horizontally and vertically both center

```
a {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.main img { top:50%; left:50%; margin: -11px 0 0 -50px; position: absolute;}
```

Is this you want?

Comment: this would work only if your all image's width and height is same.

Comment: you should add the clarification by editing the answer (there is an edit link). Comments that say important details tend to be overlooked by users and do not add much value to the answer in general.

Answer (score 0):

If your height is fixed, you could use something like this maybe?

**CSS:**

```
#div1 {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
}

#div1 img {
    line-height:100px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <img src="yourimage.jpg" />
</div>
```